# Listview with tumbnails, popup the image on press

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add something to the code so that when the user presses the thumbnail, that picture pops up or something like that, so it can be viewed 'fullscreen'.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li data-icon="false"><a href="next.php?pic=1">
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:50%"><p class="pic-wrapper"><img class="popphoto" src="images/pic1.png" width="150" height="150" /></p></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:50%"><h3>Test</h3></div>
    </a></li>
    <li data-icon="false"><a href="next.php?pic=2">
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:50%"><p class="pic-wrapper"><img src="images/pic2.png" width="150" height="150"/></p></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:50%"><h3>Test</h3></div>
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

I found some information [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/popup/) but I'm figuring since the whole cell of the list is a link/clickable, it conflicts with the tumbnail link.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In this case, `on("click", function (e) { e.target });` to retrieve clicked element and then put it in a popup.

Comment: check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mLgmz/

Comment: @Omar Thanks for the input! I got as far as that. But instead of letting the cell link to `#`, when you put in `google.com` for example , then your code doesn't work anymore. The whole cell is clickable now and it breaks the popup code... That is where I ended up as well.

Comment: just added `e.preventDefault();`. both work as expected now.

Comment: @Omar Can't seem to get it to work, but it works on your Fiddle and is exactly what I wanted. Now to integrate in my own page.. Thank you!

Comment: @Omar I got it working! If you like, you can place the code as an answer below so I can accept it and others might find it usefull as well. :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `click` event - or any other event - to `li` and check if the clicked element (`e.target`) has a `popupimg` class. If true, `preventDefault()`, amend img `src` in popup and then open it programmatically.

**JS**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page_id", function () {
    $("li").on("click", function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass("popphoto")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var photo = $(e.target).attr("src");
            $("#popupimg").find("img").attr("src", photo);
            $("#popupimg").popup({
                "dismissible": false // optional
            }).popup("open");
            // adjust popup and img height on resize
            $("#popupimg").on("popupbeforeposition", function () {
                var maxHeight = $(window).height() - 60 + "px";
                $("#popupimg, #popupimg img").css("max-height", maxHeight);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupimg" data-overlay-theme="a" data-corners="false">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mLgmz/)**